# Decoding function arguments

Tags: solidity, abi

I'm using [1inch's API](https://api.1inch.exchange/swagger/polygon/#/Swap/SwapController_getSwap) (specifically the /swap endpoint) to generate the `tx.data` payload, which I then pass to my contract under `_data`:

```
function swap(address tokenIn, uint amountIn, uint minOut, bytes calldata _data) external onlyOwner {
    IERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
    IERC20(tokenIn).approve(AGGREGATION_ROUTER_V3, amountIn);

    (bool succ, bytes memory _data) = address(AGGREGATION_ROUTER_V3).call(_data);
    if (succ) {
        (uint returnAmount, uint gasLeft) = abi.decode(_data, (uint, uint));
        require(returnAmount >= minOut);
    } else {
        revert();
    }
}
```

As the `_data` already contains the `tokenIn`, `amountIn` and `minOut`, I'm trying to remove these from my function's parameters, as well as extract other parameters. The function that ends up being called has the following signature (although I understand it's not necessarily this all the time)

```
struct SwapDescription {
    IERC20 srcToken;
    IERC20 dstToken;
    address srcReceiver;
    address dstReceiver;
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 minReturnAmount;
    uint256 flags;
    bytes permit;
 }


function swap(
    IAggregationExecutor caller,
    SwapDescription calldata desc,
    bytes calldata data
)
    external
    payable
    returns (uint256 returnAmount, uint256 gasLeft);
```

My current attempt of decoding `_data`:

```
(bytes4 sig, address _e, SwapDescription memory _desc, bytes memory _d) = abi.decode(_data, (bytes4, address, SwapDescription, bytes));
```

However this raises a `VirtualMachine: revert` error. How can I correctly decode the `_data` parameter in such a way that I can access the parameters, specifically `SwapDescription desc`?

I've also used `IAggregationExecutor` in place of `address` but I'm not sure that has a difference. Interestingly, removing the `bytes permit` struct member from the `struct SwapDescription` didn't cause any error, but lead to the wrong values of members.

Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, the following seemed to work
https://github.com/smye/1inch-swap/blob/master/contracts/SwapProxy.sol#L28